# NWJS - "No files matching" error when trying to package app

Tags: nwjs

I'm trying to package an NWJS app following various tutorials on YouTube and the web.  But I'm getting "No files matching" error and it exits.  Assuming it was because the dist/ and src/ directories hadn't been created, I created them myself, but I still get the error.  All other paths listed in package.json exist.

After searching the web for a similar issue, the only thing I found was this:

https://github.com/nwutils/nw-builder/issues/190

However, this is regarding doing the build using command line args, rather than from package.json.

npm and nodejs were updated to latest version and nwjs was updated to 0.64.0-sdk.

I am attempting the build on MacOS 10.13.6, nodejs version 16.15.0, npm version 8.5.5 .

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!
Kevin

CLI:

```
15:40:55 : ~/ReolinkNWJS
npm run prod

> ReolinkNWJS@0.0.1 prod
> nwbuild --platforms osx64 --buildDir dist/ src/

No files matching

15:41:00 : ~/ReolinkNWJS
ls
dist            icons            javascript        package-lock.json    package.json.TEMPLATE    src
html            images            node_modules        package.json        resources        styles
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReolinkNWJS",
  "description": "Reolink Client App In NWJS Framework",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "icon": "icons/app.icns",
  "main": "html/main.html",
  "chromium-args": "--enable-logging=stderr --enable-spell-checking",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "center"
  },
  "nodejs": true,
  "node-remote": "*://*",
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "nwbuild --platforms osx64 --buildDir dist/ src/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.64.0-sdk",
    "nw-builder": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need to remove your `src/` or move it to the front

- `"prod": "nwbuild --platforms osx64 --buildDir dist/"`
- `"prod": "nwbuild  src/ --platforms osx64 --buildDir dist/"`

Also, either remove or change your `node-remote`. It is currently set up so that any webpage on the internet has complete control to run Node, meaning they can easily read the contents of all files on the computer, download `virus.exe`, delete all files, whatever, literally anything. Don't do that.

`node-remote` is almost exclusively used to point to `http://localhost:8080`, or some other port, for a local webserver your app runs on. Your `main` is pointing to a local file, not a webserver, so you likely do not need `node-remote` at all.

You probably want to move the `"icon"` at the root into the `"window"` sub object.

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#window-subfields

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I changed src/ to ./ and it worked.  You are correct, I removed node-remote and it still runs.  I put it in there initially because it was a suggested fix for cross-origin issues I was having at the time with a remote page running in an iframe.

Comment: Now I am having a different issue.  I built for win64, ran with no errors, but when I run the .exe file on my Windows machine, the app opens with the NWJS splash screen instead of loading my code :-/

Comment: Learn how to package your app for distribution by hand first, then use a tool to automate it. Don't let tools automate away your understanding, just let them save you time. https://gitlab.com/TheJaredWilcurt/battery-app-workshop

Comment: YES!  This is the silver bullet I've been looking for.  Being familiar with Macos, I had always done it this way for Mac apps, as it was intuitive to me to go inside the bundle and find the code running the app inside the Resources folder.  Now needing to port my app to Windows, I had hoped for something similar for Windows, but everything I found pointed me to using the tools, so I assumed that was the only way.

Comment: In your tut you stated "packaging manually is a lot of weird tedius work", but IMO, doing it the other way was much more work.  It took me about 7 minutes.